# Do geologists ever count as "winners" in Saboteur 2?

Tags: saboteur-2

In Saboteur 2, the number of dwarves who win a round matters quite a bit: the more dwarves who win, the fewer points are awarded to each.

Geologists play by funny rules, though, and get points in another way. My question is: do geologists count toward the number of "winners" for a round, thus reducing all the other winners' points? Or are they left out of the winner count?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No**.  The geologist does not count as a winner.

As noted in the rules, they are indifferent as to who wins and loses, caring only about the crystals.